# Media query only picks up first class

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

Relevant code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "font";
}
#wrapper{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:1920px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 3.5em;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navbar .navbar-links {
  font-size: 2em;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 0.25em 2em 0 0;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.navbar #Name {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3em;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width:600px) {
  .navbar .navbar-links {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar #Name {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#Hero" id="Name" class="navbar-links">NAME</a>
    <a href="#Projects" id="Project" class="navbar-links">Projecten </a>
    <a href="#Contact" id="Contacting" class="navbar-links">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

code snippet:
https://jsfiddle.net/Nemoko/rcus95q0/

**The problem**

My problem is that when I view my navbar on a computer it shows a normal navbar,
I made it responsive by using `width:100%; margin:0;`. the problem right now is that my name still has a margin-left.

*for clarification*

The problem is not the white space. The problem is my text "namee" having a margin left but I want the margin to be gone on mobile. Somehow that doesn't work.

**What I tried**

- removing the margin with `margin:0;` but my website doesn't register it.
- Checking if it's an cache issue, but the CSS file on the website shows the line of code
- refresh the page using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>
- Use `max-width` instead of `device-max-width` but that didn't really help either.
- manually  change `margin:0;` in the browser. that works. so the code isn't wrong

This is the only media query  it registers when viewed on mobile:

[image]

I've also added my body styling for future reference.

Comment: Edited the question with the code

Comment: First thing I do on any new style-sheet:  `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` if the problem is that white space to the left.

Comment: No thats not the problem. I've edited the question in the hope it's more clear what my problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max-width:600px` instead of `max-device-width:600px` - most mobile devices have a higher screen resolution (2 to 3 times higher than the CSS width) - a `max-device-width:600px` on a device with pixel-ratio 1:2 would result in being applied only below 300px (CSS) width, which is less than most smartphones have nowadays.

The rule in the media query *does*  apply if you change that.

And to get rid of the small whitespace at the left, add `body { margin: 0; }` to reset the default margin of the body.

https://jsfiddle.net/24cyrjt0/

Comment: Forgot to add that, I used to have that aswell. I changed it to `max-device-width` to see if it would fix it. didnt fix it either.

Comment: @Nemoko If you mean the small whitespace at the left: Add `body { margin: 0; }` to reset the default margin of the body. (please note my fiddle - see edited answer)

Comment: no thats not the issue. I dont have a white space in my site. jsfiddle shows white space because of what you said. `body margin:0;` is not imported into jsfiddle because it wasnt relevant. im talking about the text "namee"

Comment: There is no text "namee". Do you mean the text "NAME" / the first nav link? What's the problem with it - in my fiddle it's at the far left when I make the screen part of the fiddle smaller than 600px, meaning the `margin-left: 0;` in the second rule of the media query is in effect. (Note: I used `max-width:600px`, as I wrote in my answer)

Comment: hmm forgot to look at your jsfiddle. dont know whats different compared to my code but thanks because it works :D